# Three.js: How to morph cube to sphere on mouse hover?

Tags: three.js, geometry, morphing

I want to know how to make a geometry morph into a different one controlled by mouse in and out. For example, when a mouse hovers on to the cube, it morphs into a sphere, but when mouse out of the object it goes back to a cube.

Similar animation to when spherizing this cube here: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_morphtargets

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this useful question, and I don't understand why it was closed as "too broad". It clearly described a very specific problem which is potentially of general interest, and received a working answer within 3 hours.

Comment: You could also mix/lerp in the vertex shader between a cube and a sphere function, using the mouse as the t value

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez That's what happens under the hood in shaders, when you use morphTargets: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/morphtarget_vertex.glsl.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`THREE.Raycaster()` with `Tween.js` library could do the trick.

Here is just an example, not the ultimate solution:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(5, 7, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var boxGeom = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10);

// this is the shortened part from the official example to create the sphere morph targets
var pos = boxGeom.attributes.position;
boxGeom.morphAttributes.position = [];
var spherePositions = [];
var v3 = new THREE.Vector3();
for (var i = 0; i < pos.count; i++) {
  v3.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i).setLength((3.5 * Math.sqrt(3) + 3.5) * 0.5);
  spherePositions.push(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);
}
boxGeom.morphAttributes.position[0] = new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(spherePositions, 3);

var boxMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "aqua",
  wireframe: true,
  morphTargets: true
});
var box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeom, boxMat);
scene.add(box);

// user's custom properties and methods
box.userData.isHovering = false;
box.userData.currentAction = null;
box.userData.toSphere = () => {
  action(1);
}
box.userData.toBox = () => {
  action(0);
}

// tweening function
function action(influence) {

  if (box.userData.currentAction) box.userData.currentAction.stop();
  
  box.userData.currentAction = new TWEEN.Tween(box.morphTargetInfluences).to({
    "0": influence
  }, 1000).start();
  
}

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var intersects = [];

window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

function onMouseMove(event) {

  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  
  intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(box);
  
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
  
    if (!box.userData.isHovering) {
    
      box.userData.toSphere();
      box.userData.isHovering = true;
      
    };
  } else {
  
    if (box.userData.isHovering) {
    
      box.userData.toBox();
      box.userData.isHovering = false;
      
    }
  }
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {

  TWEEN.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
  
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/17.4.0/Tween.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why do you say this is  _"not the ultimate solution"_, given that your code does exactly what the OP requests?

Comment: @skomisa yes, it does, but there's always something to improve :)

Comment: @prisoner849 hello, I was wondering how I would go about centering the geometry in the middle of a webpage?